# How can I stub or mock the request.subdomains method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, integration-testing, stubbing

I am trying to write some functional tests in my rails app, and in the application_controller.rb I have this:

```
before_filter :current_account
def current_account
  @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomians.first)
end
```

When running tests, `request.subdomains` doesn't contain the valid subdomains I'm looking for and makes it impossible to run any functional tests.

Is it possible to stub the `current_account` method or mock the `request.subdomains` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your functional test you should be able to do (using mocha):

```
@request.expects(:subdomains).returns(['www'])
```

Answer (score 1):

To me (and with Rails 2.3.4), the correct statement is

```
@controller.request.expects(:subdomains).returns(['www'])
```

since I cannot access to @request directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
@controller.instance_variable_set(:@request, OpenStruct.new({:subdomains => 'www'}))
```

you can access anything in ruby :)